# Use Cases with empty cells in the list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I work with a complex dataset. The most simple form of this list looks like:

```
dat1 = {{a, b, c, {}}, {d, e, f, {1}}, {h, i, j, {2}}}
```

I want to select the nested {} part.

```
Cases[dat1, {___, {a_}} :> a, Infinity]
```

The result is

```
{1, 2}
```

I want to get the result:

```
{,1, 2}
```

So the result must have the first empty cell. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here I treat the contents of the empty element as `Null` and I assume either 1 element in the nested list or no element:

```
Cases[dat1, {x_ : Null} :> x, 2]
(* returns: {Null, 1, 2} *)
```

Comment: +1. I think `Null` is the way to go. But how about simply `Cases[dat1, {___, {a_ : Null}} :> a, Infinity]`?

Comment: @C.E. Thanks, I made it even shorter.

Answer (score 11):

For this use case, I would encourage you to use `Map` and `Replace` rather than `Cases`, since you can use multiple rules for the extraction:

```
Map[Replace[{{___, {}} :> Null, {___, {x_}} :> x}],
 dat1]
(* {Null, 1, 2} *)
```

As an alternative, you can use `Replace` with a level spec:

```
Replace[dat1, {{___, {}} :> Null, {___, {x_}} :> x}, 1]
(* {Null, 1, 2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, b, c, {}}, {d, e, f, {1}}, {h, i, j, {2}}};
```

Using `Query`

```
Query[All, -1, 1] @ list
```

{Missing["PartAbsent", 1], 1, 2}

```
% /. _Missing :> Null
```

{Null, 1, 2}

As one-liner

```
Query[# /. _Missing :> Null &, -1, 1] @ list
```

{Null, 1, 2}

Answer (score 1):

```
dat1 = {{a, b, c, {}}, {d, e, f, {1}}, {h, i, j, {2}}};
```

---

Using `ReplaceAll` and `Map`:

```
dat1 /. x_List /; Length@x == 0 :> {Null} // Map[First@*Last, #] &

(*{Null, 1, 2}*)
```